# MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate method does not get called with iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, delegates, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I present MFMailComposeViewController controller and set it delegate - everything works as expected with iOS 5 but the delegate method (mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:) is not called in iOS6.

Here are code snippets:

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[controller setSubject:<text>];
[controller setMessageBody:<text> isHTML:NO];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

And the following delegate method is not called in iOS6, though the controller is successfully dismissed after Cancel or Done button is pressed:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
  if (error != nil) {
      NSLog(@"An error occurred while sending e-mail. %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }
  NSLog(@"done with e-mail");
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Any advice will be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Method viewWillAppear: of my controller presenting mailComposeController is not called either! Can it be a clue?

Comment: If necessary create a `dealloc` method for your delegate class, then put a breakpoint and/or NSLog in that method.  See if it's getting called before your mail VC is getting dismissed.

Comment: It should not be called as the delegate is a VC that is displayed after mail compose one is dismissed, shouldn't it?

Comment: "Should not be called" and "is not called" are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

The question was incorrect, as I actually used UIActivityViewController for data sharing in iOS6 and did not create/present MFMailComposeViewController. That is why I did not see the delegate method triggered.

Answer (score -1):

I have an implementation working on iOS6 and got some issues as well, werid as it sounds and dont know if it can help in your case but I changed 2 things from my iOS 5 implementation instead of using

```
controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

I used

```
[controller setMailComposeDelegate:self];
```

also, I was missing the UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol

Comment: I've tried substituting set-call for property assigning (thought it must be the same!) and, unfortunately, it didn't help! I do not implement UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol either.

Comment: BTW, I see the following message "Unable to find app identifier com.apple.mobilemail" in the output when choosing e-mail sharing on iPhone 6.0 simulator. But I did test it on the device as well, so, it cannot be the root cause.

Comment: Sorry, but probably I did not get what you meant about UINavigationControllerDelegate. Should it be implemented by the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate delegate?

Comment: The two statements above are exactly equivalent.